# Не могу добавить в источники данных БД SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2017

Установил пакеты Nuget для SQLite. В ссылках он есть. Но при этом добавить подключение я не могу, потому что в Data Source нет ничего связанного с SQLite. Что я делаю не так? [image: Окно выбора источника данных]  Пакеты Nuget по SQLite: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Visual Studio 2017.

Вообще, я хочу использовать Entity Framework с SQLite. И добавить ADO.Net provider я опять же не могу, потому что в New Connection нет ничего связанного с SQLite.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48036541/5045688 А также более старую тему: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10215488/5045688

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установи расширение https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox и будет тебе счастье

Comment: Вот [хорошая статья](http://erikej.blogspot.ru/2018/03/using-entity-framework-6-and-sqlite.html) с картинками на эту тему.

Comment: Да, как раз нашел сейчас.